# Multiple URL redirection on multiple page

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ example1.php?id1=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ example2.php?id2=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ example3.php?id3=$1
```

This code is redirecting all pages on `example1.php`

I want to redirect `example1.php` on `example1.php/title`

Similar `example2.php` on `example2.php/title`

again `example3.php` on `example3.php/title`

Please guide me, how it is possible by `htaccess`?

Comment: How do you choose whether to redirect to `example1`, `example2` or `example3` ?

Comment: Since you match all 3 on the same condition, it will always match the first rule and hence always redirect to example1. in order to answer the question we'd need to know the rule by which you want the computer to determine which page to redirect to. Right now you're giving it one rule with 3 possible outcomes. That's logically impossible to fulfil. You need to explain how the computer should distinguish which redirect to use.

Comment: First URL is http://example1.com/page1.php?id=first
I want to this http://example1.com/first

Second URL is http://example1.com/page2.php?id=second
I want to this http://example1.com/page2/second

Third URL is http://example1.com/page3.php?id=third
I want to this http://example1.com/page3/third

Comment: Dear team, this problem has been solved by adding title and subtitle like this syntax. RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ example1.php?id1=$1

RewriteRule ^id2/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ example2.php?id2=$1

RewriteRule ^id3/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ example3.php?id3=$1  Thanks to all

Comment: @RajKumarSingh if you fixed it you should you should write that in the Answers section, not comments. You're allowed to answer your own question, and then people can upvote it if they find it useful. Also your examples of the URLs should go in the _question_ not the comments too.

Answer (score 0):

this problem will be solved by below syntax.

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ **example1**.php?id1=$1

RewriteRule ^**example2**/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ **example2**.php?id2=$1

RewriteRule ^**example3**/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ **example3**.php?id3=$1

Thanks to all